# Combining multiple graphs with a loop

Tags: stata

I would like to create multiple graphs and combine them using a loop. I used the following code:

```
local var Connecticut Delaware Minnesota Missouri Rhode Island Tennessee Vermont Wisconsin Hawaii
local n: word count `var'
forvalues i=1/`n'{
local a: word `i' of `var'
line prop_report_agencies modate if statename=="`a'" , ytitle(proportion_agency reports for `a') saving(gg`a',replace)
local gg `gg' "gg`a'"
}
local gg: subinstr local gg "gg`a'" `""gg`a'""'

gr combine `gg'
graph drop _all
```

When I do this I get this error

```
ggConnecticut is not a memory graph
```

The first part of the code seems to work: the code creates graphs individually and stores them;  however, it cannot `combine` due to an error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's correct the code, while also shrinking it from a meandering stream to a straight line:

```
local S Connecticut Delaware Minnesota Missouri "Rhode Island" Tennessee Vermont Wisconsin Hawaii
foreach s of local S { 
    line prop_report_agencies modate if statename=="`s'", ytitle(proportion_agency reports for `s') saving(gg`s',replace)
    local gg `"`gg' "gg`s'""' 
}

gr combine `gg'
```

In passing, note that you had a bug as `Rhode Island` is one state, but two words.

Your major problem, however, I guess, is that there is a conflict between the role of `" "` as string delimiters and the fact you need them as literal characters in the `combine` call. To stop the `" "` being stripped you need to use compound double quotes. Your code shows that you know about them. Compound double quotes are

```
`"  "'
```

This example is dopey but nevertheless reproducible by Stata users using any recent version of Stata.

```
sysuse census, clear 

local S Alabama "Rhode Island" 
foreach s of local S { 
    histogram medage if state == "`s'", saving("gg`s'", replace) 
    local gg `"`gg' "gg`s'""'   
}

graph combine `gg'
```

In future, use

```
macro list
```

in your debugging to see what the problem is. My guess is that `" "` are missing from around `Connecticut` but present for other states.

To see the heart of the problem, consider the results of

```
local foo "bar"
mac li
```

The local macro `foo` does not include the quotation marks, as they have been stripped. To insist on them, protect them with compound double quotes.

```
local foo `""bar"' 
mac li
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that the problem was compound quotes

Comment: No; the **solution** was compound quotes!